# How to generate random points from a custom curve?

Tags: sampling, random-variable, monte-carlo

my question is how to generate random points ($\theta_1,\phi_1$) on a curve determined by :

$
\arccos\left(\cos(\theta_1)cos(\dfrac{\pi}{6})+\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{6})\cos(\phi_1)\right) = \dfrac{\pi}{6}
$

Thank you!

Comment: You defined the curve equation but not the distribution over that curve.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the curve equation
$$\arccos\left(\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{6})+\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{6})\cos(\phi_1)\right) = \dfrac{\pi}{6}$$
can be inverted into
$$\cos(\phi_1)=\dfrac{1-\cos(\theta_1)}{\sin(\theta_1)\tan(\pi/6)}=\tan(\theta_1/2)/\tan(\pi/6)\tag{1}$$
with an existing solution in $\phi_1$ when $\theta_1\in(-\pi/3,\pi/3)$, a solution to draw points "at random" (i.e., non deterministically) over that curve is to draw uniformly $\theta_1$ in $(-\pi/3,\pi/3)$ and to derive $\phi_1$ from (1), with two solutions in $(-\pi,\pi)$. As in the realisation below with $10^5$ generations:

[image]

**Be aware, though, that this distribution does not return points uniformly distributed over the curve.**

Comment: I have solved this problem following your answer,  thank you very much!

Comment: @haffner35: I am still open to alternative simulating from the Uniform distribution over the curve!